# RangeError: bignum too big to convert into `long'

Tags: ruby, irb, bignum

```
num = "0000001000000000011000000000000010010011000011110000000000000000"
for n in 0...num.length 
   temp = num[n] 
   dec =  dec + temp*(2**(num.length - n - 1))
end
puts dec
```

When i am running this code in irb the following error message is the output. and when i compiled the same logic in python it is working absolutely fine. I have Googled "RangeError: bignum too big to convert into `long': but didn't find the relevant answer. 
Please help me :( Thanks in Advance.

```
RangeError: bignum too big to convert into long'
        from (irb):4:in*'
        from (irb):4:in block in irb_binding'
        from (irb):2:ineach'
        from (irb):2
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `'
```

Comment: As I said below, Ruby has this built-in in the form of `num.to_i(2)` :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
num = "0000001000000000011000000000000010010011000011110000000000000000"
dec = 0
for n in 0...num.length 
   temp = num[n] 
   dec =  dec + temp.to_i * (2**(num.length - n - 1))
end
puts dec
```

Answer (score 5):

What you get with `num[n]` is a one character string, not a number. I rewrote your code to more idiomatic Ruby, this is how it would look like:

```
dec = num.each_char.with_index.inject(0) do |d, (temp, n)| 
  d + temp.to_i * (2 ** (num.length - n - 1))
end
```

The most idiomatic however would probably be `num.to_i(2)`, because as I see it you are trying to convert from binary to decimal, which is exactly what this does.

Comment: +1 the each_char.with_index is a really nice pattern -- new to me, so thank you.

Comment: Note that `.with_index` as a separate method was added in 1.9, before there was only `each_with_index`.