# Ruby error "bignum too big to convert into long"

Tags: ruby, openssl, rsa, long-integer, bignum

I'm trying to generate an RSA keypair in ruby with:

`OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.generate(aReallyLongBignum, 65537)`

but I am getting the following error:

`bignum too big to convert into long`

However it works in python using `RSA.construct`. Is there any way for this to work in ruby? I've looked everywhere. Really lost here. I am not trying to only take a section of this number at a time, I need to be able to pass the whole number to `RSA.generate`

Comment: @jww this is not a duplicate, that question is regarding operating on only part of a long number in a string, I need to pass the whole number in one peice

Comment: OK, taking your word on it. Sorry about that. Please *Edit* the question, and provide more code.  ***`aReallyLongBignum`*** needs to be fully specified with a sample value. (Origianl dup citation: [RangeError: bignum too big to convert into `long'](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10024212)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this using `OpenSSL::BN` and setting it after creating an instance of `OpenSSL::Pkey::RSA`

```
key   = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new
key.e = OpenSSL::BN.new(65537)
key.n = OpenSSL::BN.new(aReallyLongBignum)
```